# How to run a batch file on all sub directories within a directory?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file (ReduceFLACPadding.bat) to reduce padding in all FLAC files within a directory using metaflac.exe

These FLAC files are stored in subdirectories (one per album) within the directory E:\FLAC Library

At the moment I am processing my FLAC files one album at a time, moving the batch file to the targeted subdirectory each time. (The batch file is set to process all FLAC files within a directory)

My question is; is there a way to run this batch file on all the *.FLAC files in all the subdirectories of E:\FLAC in one go?

Please let me know if you need any more information

Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I would change the command that finds the `*.flac` files to find it recursively rather than running the batch file itself on every directory.

Comment: Hi, what would I need to change in the batch file to do this? The first line (which I believe to be the one that finds the *.flac files) is;    for %%i in (*.flac) do...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r "e:\flac" %%a in (*.flac) do echo metaflac "%%~fa" "%%~da" "%%~pa" "%%~na" "%%~xa" "%%~nxa"
```

should provide at least a clue. Without an example *metaflac* command, a more precise response would take excessive research.

From the prompt, try `for /?` for details. I've just shown with an `echo` how to construct some possible source/destination components - the rest is a matter of judicious adhesion of strings. Note the use of quotes however to properly cater for spaces in file/directorynames